# Applying abstract factory pattern for the login procedure?

Tags: java, abstract-factory

For now, I have the following

```
public interface LoginCallback{
    public void invoke();
}
public interface LoginFactory{
    public LoginCalllback getLoginCallback();
    public String getHomePage();
}
```

I'm going to have implementation for any role I currently have. For instance:

```
public class RoleManagerCallback implements LoginCallback{
    //impl
}

public class RoleManagerLoginFactory implements LoginFactory{
    public LoginCalllback getLoginCallback(){
         return new RoleManagerCallback();
    }

    public String getHomePage(){
         return "balances";
    }
}
```

The problem is that I don't exactly understand if it's really make a sense in such circumstances? Couldn't you clarify that?